# Не могу никак реализовать ListView в новом Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, listview

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_table);

    mEngWordsDBHelper = new EngWordsDBHelper(getApplicationContext(), EngWordsDBHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, 1);

    String[] words = new String[] {"girl", "satisfied", "lazy", "wardrobe", "sink", "blueberry", "strawberry", "juice"};

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_words);


    // Создаём список с связыванием его с инициалихированным массивом слов
    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, words);

    if (mAdapter == null)
        Log.d(LOG, "mAdapter is null");

    // Связывание списка с адаптером
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);


}
```

Ошибки: (ShowTableActivity.java:37)

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
                                                   at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:293)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1978)
                                                   at developer.startandroid.ru.simplesqliteapp.ShowTableActivity.onCreate(ShowTableActivity.java:37)
```

Макет:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_words"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь!!!!

Comment: mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

Comment: Проблема решена, спасибо всем кто не прошёл мимо!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас проблема в том, что вы используете `ListActivity` как супер-класс для вашей активити. А она требует, чтобы в разметке был `ListView` со строго определённым `ID`, о чём и сообщает вам в ошибке. Т.е. выполните рекомендацию из сообщения об ошибке и поставьте в разметке для `ListView` правильный id:

> @android:id/list

Т.е. разметка должны быть такая:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: надо бы инглиш потянуть

Comment: @maks_007, это никогда лишним не будет, да)

Comment: сейчас попробуем в последний раз, и если что завтра продолжим, утро вечера мудренее)), насчёт инглиша я тоже за)

Comment: спасибо за помощь

Comment: Не получается, всё та же ошибка

Comment: @Виктор, перепроверьте ещё 2 раза, что вы используете правильную разметку, правильный ID в коде и в разметке, запускаете правильную активити и что у вас в настройках студии `InstantRun` отключен. Скорее всего проблема в невнимательности)

Comment: id у листвью должно быть `android:id="@android:id/list"`

Comment: @Serodv, точно! Спс, исправил в ответе)

Answer (score 0):

Похоже просто R класс тупит..Пробовали id в ListView изменить?

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

либо вы поставили на

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_table);
```

другой layout файл..
проверьте имя в setContentView

```
(R.layout.АКТИВИТИ);
```

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_table);